# Editorial iOS : Remove first characters in each line

Tags: python, ios

I'm trying to create an Editorial workflow to remove the six first characters of each line in a file.

For now, I've builded a new worklfow composed by three steps :

1. Get selected text
2. Custom Python script
3. Replace selected text

My Python script is :

```
#coding: utf-8
import workflow

action_in = workflow.get_input()

text = open("temp.txt", "w+")
text.write(action_in)

lines = text.readlines()
for line in lines:
  text.write(line[6:])

action_out = text.read()
workflow.set_output(action_out)
```

Actually, when I try to use this workflow on a line, it just erases it.

How should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you need to close “temp.txt” and then re-open it. This works for me:

```
import workflow

action_in = workflow.get_input()

text = open("temp.txt", "w+")
text.write(action_in)
text.close()

text = open("temp.txt", "r")
lines = text.readlines()
text.close()

text = open("temp.txt", "w+")
for line in lines:
    text.write(line[6:])
text.close()

text = open("temp.txt", "r")
action_out = text.read()
workflow.set_output(action_out)
```

The “w+” in your initial “open” statement erases the file and opens it for read/write; however, the file pointer will follow the write. The safest method is to close the file when done, and re-open it to reset the file pointer and get the data you want.

Since you’re using w+, you might also be able to use .seek() to reposition the file pointer, depending on caching, however, if your outline is all you need, there’s no need to open a temporary file to perform this action.

```
import workflow

action_in = workflow.get_input()

lines = []
for line in action_in.split("\n"):
    lines.append(line[6:])

action_out = "\n".join(lines)
workflow.set_output(action_out)
```